# Could not publish to the server. java.lang.NullPointerException in Jboss7.1 Server

Tags: java, spring, jboss, server

[image]i am getting Could not publish to the server.
java.lang.NullPointerException when i try to run my Jboss7.1 server on my machine.

[image]

any idea about that??

Comment: Can you remove your project from server and then just let it start, does that also gives you this error?

Comment: still getting the same error.

Comment: added server details

Comment: Please check your server configuration. Or delete your server from your IDE and create new one with proper steps.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image]

in server properties i just clicked on Switch Location and now its running fine .

Comment: Tried this one but did not work for me / tc pivotal server in STS.

Comment: you can remove and add server again then check.

Comment: I tried that as well. I think it is some workspace related issue; the server fails when I had one of unrelated project open. When I closed it - the error went away. Cant make much sense of that.

Comment: can you change your server directory location and try again.

Answer (score 0):

@Piyush Mittal - I installed another Eclipse (newer edition) with new server and pointed it to use the old workspace. When one of projects is open - it causes the same problem with new server in new location. It seems that the issue must have something to do with workspace/project settings. I got rid of the project and problem.

Comment: create a new project and manually paste your .java and other files. do not point to the same project or workspace you used earlier because there are some other eclipse setting and classpath related files (generated by eclipse). try this and let me know if you face the same problem again.